# Is the quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ a field, where I is the ideal general by $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)\left(x^{2}+1\right)$ and $g(x)=(x+1)^{2}(x+2)^{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, quotient-spaces

When a polynomial $p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible, then we know that a quotient ring $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(p(x))$ is a field. But if we consider an ideal $I$ generated by more than one polynomial, such as  $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)\left(x^{2}+1\right)$ and  $g(x)=(x+1)^{2}(x+2)^{2}$, how do we determine if $\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$ is a field?

Comment: Do you know the Polynomial GCD theorem? That should help you reduce this to a case of a single polynomial.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is principal, so the ideal generated by $f$ and $g$ is the ideal generated by a unique polynomial $p$. Find this $p$ (**hint :** it has a link with the $\gcd$ of $f$ and $g$...), and see whether it is irreducible or not.

Comment: As an even simpler version, in this case, you should be able to show that every member of $I$ is divisible by a specific reducible polynomial (consider what the obvious candidate is), and then the factors of that polynomial are zero divisors.

Comment: Can you calculate $gcd(f,g)$?

Comment: @MarioG Yes, the GCD is $(1+x)(2+x)$.

Comment: The ideal $I$ is generated by $(1+x)(2+x)$ which is reducible, hence $I$ is not prime and the quotient ring is not a domain.